# Passing an interface type as a parameter to a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface like this:

```
interface IloginReq {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

and another interface like below:

```
export interface IReq<T = void> extends e.Request {
  body: T;
}
```

and I am passing a request to a login function that use both the interfaces as types:

```
async function login(req: IReq<IloginReq>, res: IRes) {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  // Add the jwt cookie
  const jwt = await authService.getJwt(email, password);
  const { key, options } = EnvVars.cookieProps;
  res.cookie(key, jwt, options);
  //   Return
  return res.status(HttpStatusCodes.OK).end();
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand what the meaning of this parameter declaration in login function - `req: IReq<IloginReq>` - is?

Answer (score 1):

### The Basic:

> ```js
> export interface IReq<T = void> extends e.Request {
>  body: T;
> }
> ```

It's called `Generic Type` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables). It allows you to pass another `Type` as Parameter.

You will found it on many places, even built-in utility types also `Generic Type`

`Promise<T>`: it's type for anything that asynchronous, so `Promise<string>` is asynchronous of string

`Array<T>`: it's type for array, so `Array<string | number>` is the same as `(string | number)[]`

---

### Your Code Explanation:

type `IReq` simply has a `body` property that has a type of `T`

So, `async function login(req: IReq<IloginReq>, res: IRes)` means, `req` argument is a type of `IReq<IloginReq>`,

so `req.body` has a type of `IloginReq`. Then, `req.body.email` and `req.body.password` will be accessible (also for your auto-completion, if using VS Code).

I hope it helps,

Best Regards